# How to get the current Read/Write user of an excel file using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I need to get the Name of the Read/Write user of an opened Woorkbook.

I tried already this `users = ActiveWorkbook.UserStatus` but this doesn't work as I want, I get only one user "my Name" even there is another user.

So when I open an WorkBook already opened by another user, I want to get the name of this user.

Is that possible using VBA.

Answer (score 1):

:) Any user would get its name written, if he opens it with `Environ("Username")`. Go to another PC and check it. Environ("Username") gives the name of the current Windows User.

Edit: If you are speaking about shared workbooks, this is the code:

```
Sub getListUsingUsers()
    Users = ActiveWorkbook.UserStatus
    MsgBox "Total Users using the current WorkBook: " & UBound(Users)
End Sub
```

Edit2:

```
Sub GetUsers()

Dim users           As Variant
Dim l_counter       As Long

users = ActiveWorkbook.UserStatus
Debug.Print "Total Users using the current WorkBook: " & UBound(users)

For l_counter = 1 To UBound(users)
    Debug.Print users(l_counter, 1)
Next l_counter

End Sub
```

Comment: I already tried this, but doesn't Work. So I opened this file from another computer, then I opened it from my computer and I get my Name, and not the name of the other computer

Comment: Check this out - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34612730/how-can-i-get-list-of-users-using-specific-shared-workbook

Comment: Thanks I already tried this, but in my Case this file is not a shared Excel file, and Even There is 2 or 3 users, when I execute this function I get 1 user

Comment: The same thing, did you tried this before on an excel file (not an excel shared file) ?

Comment: Then I really do not understand your scenario. Sry.