# VBA Auto Save workbook every 10 seconds without activating workbook?

Tags: vba, excel

I am using the following vba code in a workbook open event:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
On Error GoTo Message

Application.AskToUpdateLinks = False
ThisWorkbook.UpdateLinks = xlUpdateLinksNever
ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False



    Dim currentTime As Date
    currentTime = DateAdd("s", 10, Now)
    Call CurUserNames
    Application.OnTime currentTime, "SaveFile"

Exit Sub
Message:
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Exit Sub

End Sub
```

I also have this code in a module:

```
Public Sub SaveFile()

On Error GoTo Message


    ThisWorkbook.Save

    Dim currentTime As Date
    currentTime = DateAdd("s", 10, Now)

    Application.OnTime currentTime, "SaveFile"

    Exit Sub
Message:
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Exit Sub

End Sub
```

What I am trying to do is automatically save my workbook every 10 seconds.

This works.

However, something quite annoying I've noticed happens. If a user has this workbook open in the background and is working on another excel workbook then this workbook will activate and display on top of the other workbook when saving.

This can be quite annoying for the user.
Is there a way I can get my workbook to save without activating the workbook?

P.S:
For some unknown reason, this also causes the workbook to reopen when its been closed.

EDIT:

List active users in workbook code:

```
Sub CurUserNames()

Dim str As String
Dim Val1 As String

str = "Users currently online:" & Chr(10)

For i = 1 To UBound(ThisWorkbook.UserStatus)
     str = str & ThisWorkbook.UserStatus(i, 1) & ", "
Next

Val1 = DeDupeString(Mid(str, 1, Len(str) - 2))


Worksheets("Delivery Tracking").Range("F4").Value = Val1


End Sub


Function DeDupeString(ByVal sInput As String, Optional ByVal sDelimiter As String = ",") As String

    Dim varSection As Variant
    Dim sTemp As String

    For Each varSection In Split(sInput, sDelimiter)
        If InStr(1, sDelimiter & sTemp & sDelimiter, sDelimiter & varSection & sDelimiter, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
            sTemp = sTemp & sDelimiter & varSection
        End If
    Next varSection

    DeDupeString = Mid(sTemp, Len(sDelimiter) + 1)

End Function
```

Comment: 10 seconds is incredibly frequent, why not add a condition to see if the workbook actually *is* active, and skip saving otherwise? That way if the workbook actually gets changed, it'll be active, then it'll get saved every 10 seconds. Out of interest, why so amazingly frequent?

Comment: @Wolfie i need it to be frequent because users can access the workbook because its shared and in a cell i'm listing all the active users. However, this doesn't update unless the workbook is saved frequently

Comment: Re: Unknown Reason : Unless you clear out the `OnTime` events schedule when `Workbook_Close` event fires, then it will re-open it to continue the schedule. There are hundreds of examples of how to do this. Also, instead of blindly saving the file every 10 seconds, why not test if if has changed at all first and save if it has? `ThisWorkbook.Saved` will be set to `False` if the file has changed.

Comment: I agree with @CLR, there is most likely better angle of attack for this problem like an "on sheet change" event coupled with a timer. For a start, I hope this workbook is small and your network is pacey, since even a second of auto-saving every 10 seconds is a 10% productivity dive!

Comment: is the workbook opened via the VBa from an other workbook ?

Comment: Beside updating the list of active users, it's there any other reason for automatically saving the shared workbook?

Comment: @EEM No there is no other need to save other than this

Comment: Who needs to see the list of active users?  All users?  Or just management?  Saving a workbook every ten seconds is a serious bottleneck and drain on the workflow.  I would write the user's name to a delimited text file with the time he opened the book and add an onclose macro that would add the time he closed the workbook.  Then you could formulate the cells to update from the text file on refresh to get active users list on every refresh.  It takes microseconds to add or get data from a delimited text file.  Seconds to save a workbook.

Comment: @JohnMuggins each person using the shared workbook should be able to see the list of users currently working in it

Comment: @EEM See EDIT with code used to get list of users. The list gets printed into a cell and this cell needs to update each time somoene opens/closes the workbook and all users should be able to see the cell update in real time

Comment: @JohnMuggins See EDIT with code used to get list of users. The list gets printed into a cell and this cell needs to update each time somoene opens/closes the workbook and all users should be able to see the cell update in real time

Comment: Go to your data tab.  Click on share workbook.  Is there a list of names there of all people who are currently using the workbook?  Will that suffice or do you need to save these names?  You should be able to update a cell or rows from the names in that list without saving the workbook.

Answer (score 1):

Users of a shared workbook can see *`Who has this workbook open now:`* just by going to the `Review` tab in the `Ribbon` and click the `Shared Workbook` icon in the `Changes` group. This will open the `Shared Workbook` dialog box, in it the tab `Editing' shows *`Who has this workbook open now:`*. Additionally the tab 'Advance' can be used to update the settings dealing with:

- *Track changes*
- *Update changes*
- *Conflicting changes between users*
- *Include in personal view*

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Th9is example comes from [How can I get list of users using specific shared workbook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34612730/how-can-i-get-list-of-users-using-specific-shared-workbook)

It is a little overkill.  It creates a new workbook to put the users name in.  But you can modify it to put the names in whatever sheet and whatever cells you want.

Put it in the sheet module under the selection change module.  Then it will update every time the user moves to a different cell.  If it is open and he's not at his desk - it doesn't do anything.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

End Sub
```

At the bottom is the code from the above link that you can modify to suit your own needs.  It will be 1000 times better than saving a workbook every ten seconds.  Which can actually take 3 or 4 seconds itself.

If you don't want to use selection change in the worksheet module then you could put your code into the workbook module Private Sub Workbook_Open()
and put it on a timer to run every 10 seconds.  It will only take a fraction of a second instead of several seconds.

```
users = ActiveWorkbook.UserStatus
With Workbooks.Add.Sheets(1)
    For row = 1 To UBound(users, 1)
        .Cells(row, 1) = users(row, 1)
        .Cells(row, 2) = users(row, 2)
        Select Case users(row, 3)
            Case 1
                .Cells(row, 3).Value = "Exclusive"
            Case 2
                .Cells(row, 3).Value = "Shared"
        End Select
    Next
End With
```